# Weird header("Location:"); error

Tags: php, header

I've done tons of redirects using PHP's header function. This one has stumped me.

On my dashboard controller, I check whether or not the $_SESSION['loggedin'] is set. If it's not set, I want to send the user back to the main page. However, I keep getting the "too many redirects" error, even though I only have it set once. Can anyone help me out? Thanks for the help in advance!

Here's my code -

```
function index() {
    if(!isset($_SESSION['loggedin'])) {
        header("Location: ./");
    } else {
        die("The user is logged in.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`./` means "here", so yes, you're redirecting in a circle. You probably mean `/`, the *root*.

The [Location header field should really contain a complete, absolute URL](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.30) though. So you should redirect to `http://example.com/`. Relative URLs just happen to be (incorrectly) accepted by some browsers.

Answer (score 2):

This is because you just refresh the page. It means the user isn't redirected to different URL, he stays where he were.

You're using wrong path for `Location` header. `./` is equal to `.` which is a relative path and means *current path*. Certainly, you want to use `/` which is absolute path, ie. it's related to domain's root.

Answer (score 0):

I would use absolute paths it will reduce possible errors.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to use global to access the session variables in your case.